# How to pass a Linq Expression in lieu a Predicate?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been reading articles and SO posts for the last couple of hours about building my own Linq Expressions dynamically, then using those as predicates to filter items in a List or and Array.

Here's a simple example of what I have so far:

```
public class AWDRiskMRASCodeXref
{
    public string RiskSubType { get; set; }
    public string AcordReqCodeInt { get; set; }
    public string MrasReqCodeInt { get; set; }
    public string AcordReqCodePpe { get; set; }
    public string MrasReqCodePpe { get; set; }
    public string AcordReqCodeWeb { get; set; }
    public string MrasReqCodeWebS { get; set; }
}
```

I will then use something like Dapper to retrieve the list from the database;

```
var items =  conn.Query<AWDRiskMRASCodeXref>("SELECT RiskSubType, AcordReqCodeInt, MrasReqCodeInt, AcordReqCodePpe, MrasReqCodePpe, AcordReqCodeWeb, MrasReqCodeWeb FROM LKUP_AWDRiskMRASCodeXref;").ToList();

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AWDRiskMRASCodeXref), "x");
var member = Expression.Property(param, "AcordReqCodePpe"); //x.AcordReqCodePpe
var constant = Expression.Constant("1004700009");
var body = Expression.Equal(member, constant); //x.AcordReqCodePpe == "1004700009"
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<AWDRiskMRASCodeXref, bool>>(body, param); //x => x.AcordReqCodePpe == "1004700009"
finalExpression.Dump();
```

The finalExpression "x => (x.AcordReqCodePpe == "1004700009")" looks great in LinqPad, but what do I need to do the the express to enable it to be passed the the following Linq query?

```
var item = items.FirstOrDefault(finalExpression);
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already pulled the data from your database, all you need to do for your expression to work is to compile it and pass it to `FirstOrDefault` extension method instead.

```
var compiledExpression = finalExpression.Compile();
var item = items.FirstOrDefault(compiledExpression);
```

As a bonus tip, if you're using `.NET Framework 4.6` or higher. You could use the `nameof` operator while generating your `member` property. It's much better than the hardcoded string, if you ever change the name of your property. It'd look like this:

```
var member = Expression.Property(param, nameof(AWDRiskMRASCodeXref.AcordReqCodePpe));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have already 'resolved' the query when you called `.ToList()` on the query. Remove that so that your query reads something like:

```
var item = conn.Query<AWDRiskMRASCodeXref>("SELECT RiskSubType, AcordReqCodeInt, MrasReqCodeInt, AcordReqCodePpe, MrasReqCodePpe, AcordReqCodeWeb, MrasReqCodeWeb FROM LKUP_AWDRiskMRASCodeXref;")
    .FirstOrDefault(finalExpression);
```

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to use the expression on a collection that has already been materialized?

Comment: You can. The `Dump()` returns a `string` of the body. You need to call `Compile()` on `finalExpression`